# Use compiled ffpmeg library in different Android projects

Tags: android, linux, windows, android-ndk, ffmpeg

I've compiled ffmpeg library for usage in my Android apps, so now I have *.so files and I want to use them in other Android projects. 
But I've compiled them in Linux and now I am going to work in Windows. Can I just put these compiled files to my project in Windows link them in mk file and use? Does difference between 32 and 64 bit OS play role? 
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "work in Windows"? Do you mean that you are writing an Android app, with Windows as the OS of your development machine? Or do you mean that you are building a Windows app?

Comment: I mean, that Windows is OS of my development machine. Early I worked in Ubuntu and compiled ffmpeg libs there and now I am migrating  to Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your target android platform is the same, it should work.

The .so file generated by Android NDK compiler is native code of the target android platform.
It is just packed into the APK intact, so the OS you use to pack the APK doesn't affect the outcome.

EDIT:

1. As a commenter suggested, by target platform I meant CPU architectures like ARM, x86 or MIPS
2. As to the API level, neither targetSdkVersion nor minSdkVersion doesn't directly affect the native code.

   Rather, your code may fail at runtime, if you use higher level API than is available on the actual Android device.

   To avoid this safely, you need to set your minSdkVersion according to the NDK API level which was assumed when compiling your .so file.

   In other words, files under "<your-ndk-dir>/platforms/android-<NDK-API-level>/arch-<CPU type>/usr/..." should have been looked up by the NDK compiler when you compiled your native code. Identify which level was used, and make sure you have equal or greater number as minSdkVersion.

   If you have NDK installed, it's documented in "<your-ndk-dir>/docs/STABLE-APIS.html".

Comment: Thank You! Only target SDK? MinRequired SDK may be different?

Comment: minSdk may be different. But there may be different Android device CPU architectures: arm v6 (armeabi) or arm v7 (armeabi-v7a), Intel Atom (x86), or maybe MIPS.

Comment: @user1885632 added information about minSdkVersion to my answer.